# Wordpress Theme Compatibility Issue

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, themes, admin, compatibility

I'm developing a WP theme for a client and have run into some trouble.

When my theme is activated:

I edit  post or page (or several other areas), click UPDATE, PUBLISH, etc - and I get a blank white page.

When I go back, the post has been updated - so the system is working, it just isn't redirecting me back to the edit page.

Everything works fine when the default template is activated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trace the error set the WP_DEBUG as true

Refer : http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-easily-enabledisable-debug-mode-in-wordpress

Comment: Its `WP_DEBUG` and not `DEBUG_MODE`

Comment: Tried WP_DEBUG - had one error related to a plugin, which I fixed, and now have no other errors.

Comment: @NathanHackley - So still you are viewing the blank page?

Comment: Yes. Still having same issue.

Comment: @NathanHackley : Just comment the codes in the functions.php, which is common for both the user and admin side. Then trace line by line. Check for admin_init hook if you have given.

Comment: When I comment out the entire functions.php file, there is no change in behavior

Comment: Sorry this took so long. I found the error and it was in functions.php. I had a filename mixup. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php` file located in the WordPress root folder, and then you will be able to see the errors that are coming up. Fixing those errors will resolve your problem.

Comment: Tried WP_DEBUG - had one error related to a plugin, which I fixed, and now have no other errors.